# Populate Gridview rows based upon values entered in controls present outside the Grid

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want a gridview which will populating values based upon some textbox values outside the grid. For reference 
[image]

Help me achieve this functionality :

If Text Quantity is 3 , then 3 Gridview rows will be loaded on subsequent click event of linkbutton Charge To(Requestor) .
Data in other text boxes , how to get that into date columns of gridview.
Total Amount in the top gridview is divided by 3 in the lower gridview.

Comment: show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

[Please see the below image which i accomplished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQW7y.png)

I have still some enhancements to make:

The count of Gridview rows are based upon the number of charging in Textbox.
Another functionality which i want to achieve is display the Charging date mentioned in the textbox will be displayed in the manner highlighted in red boundery.
Date should be displayed in a span of 1 month gap prior to textbox value.